# C# offset a point perpendicular to a given line segment

Tags: c#

I have a line segment defined by two PointD (a custom type to work with doubles rather than floats, as the Math in C# works in doubles): p1 (.541, 41.929), p2 (363.736, 88.48) - assume that the line will be sloped.

At unpredictable intervals, I need to set an offset point perpendicular to the segment a variable distance- lets just say, 0.125, 0.25, etc..

It seems all the example out there assume that you'll always need this perpendicular point to be based on the mid point.

I have solved for p3 by: (

```
private PointD subPt(PointD a, PointD b, double p)
    {
        double x = (1 - p) * a.X + p * b.X;
        double y = (1 - p) * a.Y + p * b.Y;

        return new PointD(x, y);
    }
```

The return point for 0.25 is (91.339, 53.566). I have validated this in cad to be accurate enough for my requirements.

The thing I cannot figure out for the life of me, is how to then get a perpendicular point 5 (just to make it round) away from the line.

The results I am expecting are p4 (90.705, 58.526)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to solve for p4. I used cad to find to get a solution.

Comment: A **math** question rather than C#.

Comment: Lei Yang - while it might be more math based, there an overwhelming number of existing C# threads that are incorrectly answered- so unless you have a working C# implementation of this supposed math problem, your comment is completely useless, and I challenge you to put your money where your mouth is, and come up with working solution.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a math question, not a programming question.

Comment: Vaccano - Did you not see the PROGRAMMING ANSWER. If you took 1/2 a minute to search, you'd see that is this is a common (and properly unanswered) question. SOOOO rather than knock it, vote the answer up so it helps others in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have come up with a working C# implementation:

```
/// <summary>
/// Create a perpendicular offset point at a position located along a line segment.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="a">Input. PointD(x,y) of p1.</param>
/// <param name="b">Input. PointD(x,y) of p2.</param>
/// <param name="position">Distance between p1(0.0) and p2 (1.0) in a percentage.</param>
/// <param name="offset">Distance from position at 90degrees to p1 and p2- non-percetange based.</param>
/// <param name="c">Output of the calculated point along p1 and p2. might not be necessary for the ultimate output.</param>
/// <param name="d">Output of the calculated offset point.</param>
private void PerpOffset(PointD a, PointD b, double position, double offset, out PointD c, out PointD d)
{
    //p3 is located at the x or y delta * position + p1x or p1y original.
    PointD p3 = new PointD(((b.X - a.X) * position) + a.X, ((b.Y - a.Y) * position) + a.Y);

    //returns an angle in radians between p1 and p2 + 1.5708 (90degress).
    double angleRadians = Math.Atan2(a.Y - b.Y, a.X - b.X) + 1.5708;

    //locates p4 at the given angle and distance from p3.
    PointD p4 = new PointD(p3.X + Math.Cos(angleRadians) * offset, p3.Y + Math.Sin(angleRadians) * offset);

    //send out the calculated points
    c = p3;
    d = p4;
}
```

Additionally, here is my PointD class. Basically just easier to store and work with the x,y values as doubles, and contains a property to return a PointF for graphics output purposes.

```
public class PointD
{
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }

    public float Xf { get { return (float)X; } }
    public float Yf { get { return (float)Y; } }

    public PointF PointF { get { return new PointF(Xf, Yf); } }

    public PointD()
    { }

    public PointD(double cX, double cY)
    {
        X = cX;
        Y = cY;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("[{0}, {1}]", X, Y);
    }
}
```